# Create a tree from a list of strings containing paths of files - javascript

Tags: javascript, path, tree

Let's assume I have the following array:

```
[
    "About.vue", 
    "Categories/Index.vue", 
    "Categories/Demo.vue", 
    "Categories/Flavors.vue"
]
```

We use the `Index.vue` in each sub-folder to act as the parent of that folder. That means the above would look like:

```
[
  { 
    name: "About", 
    children: [] 
  }, 
  { 
    name: "Categories", 
    children: 
    [
      {
        name: "Index.vue", 
        children: [] 
      },
      {
        name: "Demo.vue", 
        children: [] 
      },
      { 
        name: "Flavors.vue", 
        children: [] 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I was able to get it working slightly by using the following tutorial: https://joelgriffith.net/array-reduce-is-pretty-neat/

However, the thing about that is that it is a root object with a property for each file, as opposed to an array with an object for each file.

The following code produces the intended output:

```js
let paths = [
    "About.vue", 
    "Categories/Index.vue", 
    "Categories/Demo.vue", 
    "Categories/Flavors.vue"
];


let helper = {
  index: -1,
  name: ""
};

function treeify(files) {
  var fileTree = [];

  function mergePathsIntoFileTree(prevDir, currDir, i, filePath) {

    helper.name = currDir;
    helper.index = i;
      
    if (helper.index == 0) {
      let index = prevDir.findIndex(x => x.name == helper.name);
      if (index < 0) {
        prevDir.push({
          name: helper.name,
          children: []
        });
      }
      
      return prevDir;
    }
    
    if (helper.index >= 0) {
      let obj = {
        name: currDir,
        children: []
      };
      
      prevDir[helper.index].children.push(obj);
      helper.index = i;
      helper.name = currDir;
    }
   
  }

  function parseFilePath(filePath) {
    var fileLocation = filePath.split('/');

    // If file is in root directory, eg 'index.js'
    if (fileLocation.length === 1) {
      fileTree[0] = {
        name: fileLocation[0],
        children: []
      };
    } else {
      fileLocation.reduce(mergePathsIntoFileTree, fileTree);
    }
  }

  files.forEach(parseFilePath);

  return fileTree;
}

console.log(treeify(paths));
```

However, it fails on the following input:

```
let paths = [
    "About.vue", 
    "Categories/Index.vue", 
    "Categories/Demo.vue", 
    "Categories/Flavors.vue",
    "Categories/Types/Index.vue",
    "Categories/Types/Other.vue"
];
```

Does anyone know a solution to get it working for further nested lists of paths?

Comment: Originally posted 2 hours ago, however didn't include any attempted code. I've deleted that and recreated this question, including the attempted code.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can create this structure using `forEach` method to loop each path and split it to array on `/`, then you can also use `reduce` method to create nested objects.

```js
let paths = ["About.vue","Categories/Index.vue","Categories/Demo.vue","Categories/Flavors.vue","Categories/Types/Index.vue","Categories/Types/Other.vue"];

let result = [];
let level = {result};

paths.forEach(path => {
  path.split('/').reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
    if(!r[name]) {
      r[name] = {result: []};
      r.result.push({name, children: r[name].result})
    }
    
    return r[name];
  }, level)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi, I have made the code a bit more verbose, and added comments to try and understand it. Can you please let me know if my comments are correct? https://pastebin.com/1LT0guzs

Thanks.

Comment: This code will not work if a path contains "result". A simple workaround would be to rename "result" to "<result>", that is, include characters that cannot appear in a path.

Comment: @SamuelRowe it would be bullet proof if the name "result" was replaced with any name contained "/" symbol, as we use it internally for `split`. So it's guarantied that there will be no path could break the solution.

Answer (score 3):

So, first off, I am going to assume this is in Node.js, second, I am currently at home so I don't have access to node.js at the moment so I had no real way of testing the code, however the following code should work.

What you need to do is check the contents of the folder and then make a check to see if an item in the folder is a directory or not, if true, call the function again with the new path (a.k.a. recursion).

So first you start by reading the folder, add each item's name to the `.name` property of the object, then you check if it's a folder or not, if it is, recursive for that path. Keep returning an array of objects back (this will be added to the `.children` property.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var filetree = DirToObjectArray('path/to/folder/');

function DirToObjectArray(path) {
        var arr = [];
    var content =  fs.readdirSync(path, { withFileTypes: true });
        for (var i=0; i< content.length; i++) {
        var obj = new Object({
        name: "",
        children: []
     });

     obj.name = content[i].name;

     if (content[i].isDirectory()) {
       obj.children = DirToObjectArray(path + content[i].name + "/");
     }

            arr.push(obj);
   }
   return arr;
}
```

If you are not using node.js but in-browser javascript, I can't help you with that

Answer (score 2):

You could take an iterative approach for every found name part and get an object and return the children for the next search.

```js
var paths = ["About.vue", "Categories/Index.vue", "Categories/Demo.vue", "Categories/Flavors.vue", "Categories/Types/Index.vue", "Categories/Types/Other.vue"],
    result = paths.reduce((r, p) => {
        var names = p.split('/');
        names.reduce((q, name) => {
            var temp = q.find(o => o.name === name);
            if (!temp) q.push(temp = { name, children: [] });
            return temp.children;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with [@Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620771/nenad-vracar)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57344801/8605652) (and upvoted, thank you!), but I also had the need to allow duplicate filenames in my use case. I just wanted to share how I did that.

```js
let paths = ["About.vue","Categories/Index.vue","Categories/Demo.vue","Categories/Flavors.vue","Categories/Types/Index.vue","Categories/Types/Other.vue","Categories/Types/Other.vue","Categories/Types/Other.vue"];

let result = [];
let level = {result};

paths.forEach(path => {
  path.split('/').reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
    if(!r[name]) {
      r[name] = {result: []};
      r.result.push({name, children: r[name].result});
    } else if (i === a.length - 1) {
      // Allow duplicate filenames.
      // Filenames should always be at the end of the array.
      r.result.push({name, children: []});
    }
    
    return r[name];
  }, level)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution was derived from @nenad-vracar's answer. One shortcoming with his answer is that if a path contains "result", the code will fail. A simple workaround would be to rename "result" to "", that is, include characters that cannot appear in a path.

```js
export interface IPathNode {
  name: string;
  children: IPathNode[];
  path: IPath | null;
}

export interface IPath {
  key: string;
  directory: boolean;
}

interface IPathLevel {
  // ["<result>"]: IPathNode[];
  [key: string]: IPathLevel | IPathNode[];
}

export const createPathTree = (paths: IPath[]): IPathNode | null => {
  const level: IPathLevel = { ["<result>"]: [] as IPathNode[] };

  paths.forEach((path) => {
    path.key.split("/").reduce(
      ((
        currentLevel: IPathLevel,
        name: string,
        index: number,
        array: string[]
      ) => {
        if (!currentLevel[name]) {
          currentLevel[name] = { ["<result>"]: [] };
          (currentLevel["<result>"] as IPathNode[]).push({
            name,
            children: (currentLevel[name] as IPathLevel)[
              "<result>"
            ] as IPathNode[],
            /* Attach the path object to the leaf node. */
            path: index === array.length - 1 ? path : null,
          });
        }

        return currentLevel[name];
      }) as any,
      level
    );
  });

  const finalArray = level["<result>"] as IPathNode[];
  return finalArray.length > 0 ? finalArray[0] : null;
};

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    createPathTree([
      {
        key: "/components/button.tsx",
        directory: false,
      },
      {
        key: "/components/checkbox.tsx",
        directory: false,
      },
      {
        key: "/result",
        directory: true,
      },
    ]),
    null,
    4
  )
);
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "components",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "button.tsx",
                    "children": [],
                    "path": {
                        "key": "/components/button.tsx",
                        "directory": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "checkbox.tsx",
                    "children": [],
                    "path": {
                        "key": "/components/checkbox.tsx",
                        "directory": false
                    }
                }
            ],
            "path": null
        },
        {
            "name": "result",
            "children": [],
            "path": {
                "key": "/result",
                "directory": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "path": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is inspired from @Nenad Vracar. But unlike his solution where he used for each and reduce which I think unnecessary.

```
let final = {result:[]};

for (const path of paths) {
  let context = final;
  
  for (const name of path.split('/')) {
    if (!context[name]) {
      context[name] = {result:[]};
      context.result.push({name, children: context[name].result});
    }
    
    context = context[name];
  }
}

console.log(final.result)
```