# How to convert string path to JSON parent-child tree using node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6, treeview

I have been trying to convert an array of paths to the `JSON` parent-child tree using `node js`. I am following @Nenad Vracar answer for building the tree [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344694/create-a-tree-from-a-list-of-strings-containing-paths-of-files-javascript). I am using the mentioned answer which I have slightly modified. Below is my code:

```
function buildTree(obj) {
  let result = [];
  let level = {
    result
  };

  obj.forEach(item => {
    if (typeof item.fsLocation != "undefined") {
      var obj = {}
      var path = ""
      item.fsLocation.split('/').reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
        path += "/"+name

        if (!r[name]) {
          r[name] = {
            result:[]
          };
          obj = {
            name,
            children: r[name].result
          }
          if(r[name].result.length < 1){
            obj["path"] = item.fsLocation
            obj["fileSize"] = item.fileSize
            obj["createDate"] = item.createDate
            obj["editDate"] = item.editDate
            obj["fileType"] = item.fileType
            obj["version"] = item.version
          }
          r.result.push(obj)
        }
        return r[name];
      }, level)
    }
  })
  return result
}
```

`obj`:

```
[
   {
      "createDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
      "fileType":"pptx",
      "fsLocation":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity/technology.pptx",
      "fileSize":46845322,
      "fileName":"technology.pptx",
      "editDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
      "version":"10.0"
   },
   {
      "fileName":"operations.pptx",
      "fileSize":23642178,
      "fileType":"pptx",
      "fsLocation":"Events/Plays/Technologies/operations.pptx",
      "createDate":"2019-01-08T08:00:00Z",
      "editDate":"2019-01-09T08:00:00Z",
      "version":"15.0"
   },
   {
      "fileName":"Solution.pdf",
      "createDate":"2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
      "fileSize":275138,
      "fsLocation":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Solution.pdf",
      "fileType":"pdf",
      "editDate":"2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
      "version":"1.0"
   }
]
```

Using that above code my output is like below:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Events",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"Plays",
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"Technologies",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"Continuity",
                        "children":[
                           {
                              "name":"technology.pptx",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity/technology.pptx",
                              "fileSize":46845322,
                              "createDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
                              "editDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
                              "fileType":"pptx",
                              "version":"10.0"
                           }
                        ],
                        "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity/technology.pptx",
                        "fileSize":46845322,
                        "createDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
                        "editDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
                        "fileType":"pptx",
                        "version":"10.0"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Technologies",
                        "children":[
                           {
                              "name":"operations.pptx",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/operations.pptx",
                              "fileSize":23642178,
                              "createDate":"2019-01-08T08:00:00Z",
                              "editDate":"2019-01-09T08:00:00Z",
                              "fileType":"pptx",
                              "version":"15.0"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"Solution.pdf",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Solution.pdf",
                              "fileSize":275138,
                              "createDate":"2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
                              "editDate":"2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
                              "fileType":"pdf",
                              "version":"1.0"
                           }
                        ],
                        "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/operations.pptx",
                        "fileSize":23642178,
                        "createDate":"2019-01-08T08:00:00",
                        "editDate":"2019-01-09T08:00:00Z",
                        "fileType":"pptx",
                        "version":"15.0"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I would like to get output like below

```
[
   {
      "name":"Events",
      "path":"Events",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"Plays",
            "path":"Events/Plays",
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"Technologies",
                  "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"Continuity",
                        "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity",
                        "children":[
                           {
                              "name":"technology.pptx",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity/technology.pptx",
                              "fileSize":46845322,
                              "createDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
                              "editDate":"2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
                              "fileType":"pptx",
                              "version":"10.0"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Technologies",
                        "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies",
                        "children":[
                           {
                              "name":"operations.pptx",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/operations.pptx",
                              "fileSize":23642178,
                              "createDate":"2019-01-08T08:00:00Z",
                              "editDate":"2019-01-09T08:00:00Z",
                              "fileType":"pptx",
                              "version":"15.0"
                           },
                           {
                              "name":"Solution.pdf",
                              "children":[
                                 
                              ],
                              "path":"Events/Plays/Technologies/Solution.pdf",
                              "fileSize":275138,
                              "createDate":"2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
                              "editDate":"2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
                              "fileType":"pdf",
                              "version":"1.0"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Any idea of how to produce the above output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always favor readability over fancy:

```js
const arr = [{
    "fileName": "operations.pptx",
    "fileSize": 23642178,
    "fileType": "pptx",
    "fsLocation": "Events/Plays/Technologies/operations.pptx",
    "createDate": "2019-01-08T08:00:00Z",
    "editDate": "2019-01-09T08:00:00Z",
    "version": "15.0"
  },
  {
    "createDate": "2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
    "fileType": "pptx",
    "fsLocation": "Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity/technology.pptx",
    "fileSize": 46845322,
    "fileName": "technology.pptx",
    "editDate": "2019-10-03T07:00:00Z",
    "version": "10.0"
  },
  {
    "fileName": "Solution.pdf",
    "createDate": "2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
    "fileSize": 275138,
    "fsLocation": "Events/Plays/Technologies/Solution.pdf",
    "fileType": "pdf",
    "editDate": "2016-06-16T22:42:16Z",
    "version": "1.0"
  }
]

const tree = {
  name: 'root',
  path: '',
  children: []
}

for (const e of arr) {
  let node = tree
  const nodenames = e.fsLocation.split('/')
  while (nodenames.length > 0) {
    const nodename = nodenames.shift()
    if (!node.children.map(e => e.name).includes(nodename)) {
      node.children.push({
        name: nodename,
        path: [node.path, nodename].join('/'),
        children: []
      })
    }
    node = node.children.filter(e => e.name === nodename)[0]
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```

returns tree:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "path": "",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Events",
      "path": "/Events",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Plays",
          "path": "/Events/Plays",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Technologies",
              "path": "/Events/Plays/Technologies",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "operations.pptx",
                  "path": "/Events/Plays/Technologies/operations.pptx",
                  "children": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "Continuity",
                  "path": "/Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "technology.pptx",
                      "path": "/Events/Plays/Technologies/Continuity/technology.pptx",
                      "children": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name": "Solution.pdf",
                  "path": "/Events/Plays/Technologies/Solution.pdf",
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```